# retaining all the values of a key value search in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a declaration

```
There are couple of values which satisfies the search criteria, but the first value is overwritten by the second and I could see only one value.
```

Do I need to use a different data type ?

Example :

I am having a list as:

```
[ [ name1:a, name2:b, name3:c, name4:d, other:1, other1:2 ],
  [ name1:a, name2:a, name3:b, name4:c, other:3, other1:4],  
  [ name1:a, name2:b, name3:c, name4:d, other:2, other1:3] ]
```

so what I would desire is for groupBy of name1, name2, name3, name4

--> we have [other:1, other1:2] and [other:2, other1:3]

is it possible to include multiple keys in the groupBy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Maps` can only have one entry per key.

You can have a list of values for a map though, like `[ key:[ val1, val2 ] ]`.

If your original data is in a list of maps, maybe `groupBy` would help? ie:

```
def data = [ [ name:'a', value:1 ],
             [ name:'b', value:1 ],
             [ name:'a', value:1 ] ]

def result = data.groupBy { it.name }

assert result == [ a:[ [ name:'a', value:1 ],
                       [ name:'a', value:1 ] ],
                   b:[ [ name:'b', value:1 ] ] ]

assert result.a == [ [ name:'a', value:1 ], [ name:'a', value:1 ] ]
```

Using your example, you can do:

```
def list = [ [ name1:'a', name2:'b', name3:'c', name4:'d', other:1, other1:2 ],
             [ name1:'a', name2:'a', name3:'b', name4:'c', other:3, other1:4],  
             [ name1:'a', name2:'b', name3:'c', name4:'d', other:2, other1:3] ]

list.groupBy { [ name1:it.name1, name2:it.name2, name3:it.name3, name4:it.name4 ] }.collectEntries { k, v ->
    [ k, v.collect { [ other:it.other, other1:it.other1 ] } ]
}
```

Which gives you the output Map:

```
[ ['name1':'a', 'name2':'b', 'name3':'c', 'name4':'d']:[['other':1, 'other1':2], ['other':2, 'other1':3]],
  ['name1':'a', 'name2':'a', 'name3':'b', 'name4':'c']:[['other':3, 'other1':4]]]
```

You mean like that?

### Edit

Without using `collectEntries`, this might work:

```
list.groupBy { [ name1:it.name1, name2:it.name2, name3:it.name3, name4:it.name4 ] }
    .inject( [:] ) { map, key, value ->
        map[ key ] = value.collect { [ other:it.other, other1:it.other1 ] }
        map
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim, is it possible to include multiple keys in the group by(I am editing my question with an example)

Comment: I mean the same Tim, but my versio is 1.5.6 so I believe collectEntries or collect doesnt work...

Comment: @Techie Oh... That's over 5 years old...  You can't upgrade?

Comment: that is our limitation Tim, we are using groovy as a script in one of the customized tools :-)

Comment: could you please let me know how to retrieve the result without using collectEntries ?

Comment: @Techie I'll have a think...  This sort of massively important information should probably go in the question next time ;-)

Comment: as collectEntries is not working, I used findAll as of now to test, it seems working(groupBy)

Comment: You can just use the `groupBy` and drop the `collectEntries` bit, you'll just have the `nameX` data in the results

Comment: @Techie Got round to looking at this again, and added a version that uses `inject` rather than `collectEntries` to filter the values to just contain `other` and `other1`.  Hope it works and helps :-)  Good luck! :-)